# Text doesnot rotate Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d

I checked on site and followed all examples.
    I have written the code, the position, font of text changes but the angle or rotation doesnt take place. Any help advice pointers are much appreciated

```
int x = X;
    int y = Y;
    int w = 9;
    int h = 9;
    int fontsize = 7;

    Rectangle bounds = new java.awt.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    ShapeGroup group = new ShapeGroup();
    group.setAnchor(bounds);
    slide.addShape(group);

    Graphics2D graphics = new PPGraphics2D(group);
    AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
    affineTransform.rotate(50);

    java.awt.Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 9, 9);
    graphics.draw(circle);
    graphics.setPaint(colorRating);
    graphics.fill(circle);

    //graphics.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
    graphics.setColor(new Color(159, 78, 15));
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontsize);
    Font rotatedFont = font.deriveFont(affineTransform);
    graphics.setFont(rotatedFont);
    graphics.setTransform(affineTransform);
    graphics.drawString(siteName, x + 11, y + fontsize + 1);
    graphics.setFont(font);
```

Comment: `PPGraphics2D`?  What library is this from?

Comment: @AJNeufeld, library is from org.apache.poi.hslf.model

Answer (score 0):

I reported a similar bug to vldocking project: when used on MacOS, tab titles didn’t rotate 90° when the tabs were on the left/right. After investigating further, I submitted a patch, which amounted to one line:

```
    graphics.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Without antialiasing, the text rendering took an optimized path, which skipped the ability to rotate the glyphs.

I don’t know if you are on a MacOS, with the same java implementation.  Try setting the antialiasing attribute, and if that doesn’t work, some other rendering hints as well.

Good luck!